# Counting unique characters in string given by user C programming

Tags: c

Write a program that prompts the user to enter a string and prints the goodness of the string. The goodness of a string in general, is calculated in the following way: If the string contains any letters except for 0 or 1, then its goodness is 0. Otherwise, its goodness is the number of 1's in the string.

```
int numZeros, numOnes, i;
char sent[50];
i = 0;


printf("Enter a string with no spaces: ");
scanf(" %s", sent);

for(i=0; i != '\0'; ++i){
    if(sent[i] == '0'){
        ++numZeros;
    }
    else if(sent[i] != '\0'){
        ++numOnes;
    }
}


if((numOnes == 0) && (numZeros == 0)){
    printf("\nGoodness of the input is 0\n");
}
else if((numZeros > 0) && (numOnes == 0)){
    printf("\nGoodness of the input is 0\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nGoodness of the input is %d\n", numOnes);
}

return 0;
```

Could someone please explain why in the last else statement, when i call and try to display the value of variable "numOnes" i will get some obsure number, even if I input a specific number of 1's into a sentence?

Comment: Because you never initialize the variables.

Comment: You never set `numOnes` to a value so it will just be the value of whatever is in memory at the time. That's why it's an obscure number.

Comment: your `for` loop never executes, you initialize `i` to 0, then loop on the condition `i != 0`. I think you mean `sent[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: **Title doesn't match content.** Counting `1`-s in a string doesn't involve counting the unique characters.

Comment: All of these issues can be found with a debugger.

Comment: should i just have it say counting characters then?

Comment: Rollback :Edit which incorporates the answer defaced the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `else if( sent[i]!='0')` ...
- Initialize `numOnes` `numZeros`.
- for loop will be `for(i=0;sent[i]!='\0';i++)`

Also you can simplify the print logic. Calculate the length of the input.

```
if(numZeroes+numOnes < len )
// Goodness is zero
else
 // Goodness is numOnes
```

Implementation:

```
int main()
{
    int numZeros=0, numOnes=0;
    char sent[50];
    printf("Enter a string with no spaces: ");
    scanf(" %s", sent);

    for(int i=0; sent[i]; ++i)
        (sent[i]=='0')?numZeros++:numOnes++;

    printf("Goodness of the input is %d", (numOnes+numZeros<strlen(sent))?0:numOnes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, i forgot to initialize the numOnes and numZeros due to my school requiring declaration and initialization to be on separate lines. I also noticed a few logical errors mentioned above that i should have been able to catch myself. The programs works now

Comment: @TylerGee.: Your school asks you to declare and initialize in separate lines?

Comment: i thought it was weird but this is the rule in the style guide

Comment: "- variables are initialized separately from being declared."

Comment: I cannot link the style guide to you but i can post it in a comment if you wish? It is only about 20 lines. above i have already posted the specific line dedicated to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
int main(){
    int numZeros = 0, numOnes = 0, i;
    bool ver = true;
    char sent[50];
    i = 0;

    printf("Enter a string with no spaces: ");
    scanf(" %s", sent);

    for(i=0; sent[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(sent[i] == '0')
            ++numZeros;
        else if(sent[i] == '1')
            ++numOnes;
        else{
            ver = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(ver){
        if((numOnes == 0) && (numZeros == 0))
            printf("\nGoodness of the input is 0\n");
        else if((numZeros > 0) && (numOnes == 0))
            printf("\nGoodness of the input is 0\n");
        else
            printf("\nGoodness of the input is %d\n", numOnes);
    }else{
        printf("\nGoodness of the input is 0\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You do not need any extra library.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a property called "almost-goodness" recursively, and write a recursive solution. C strings support recursion very well because if `s` is a non-empty C string, then `s + 1` (one byte higher address) is also a C string, representing the suffix which remains after the first character of `s`.

```
/* almost_goodness returns -1 if the string contains
   bad characters, otherwise the count of 1's. */

static int almost_goodness(const char *str)
{
   switch (*str) {
   case 0: /* null terminator: empty string */
     return 0;
   case '0':
   case '1':
     {
        int ag_rest = almost_goodness(str + 1);
        return ag_rest < 0 ? ag_rest : (*str == '1') + ag_rest;
     }
   default:
     return -1;
   }
}

int goodness(const char *str)
{
   int ag = almost_goodness(str);
   return ag < 0 ? 0 : ag;
}
```

Almost-goodness is defined as this:

- If the string is empty, its almost-goodness is zero.
- If the first character of the string is other than `1` or `0`, its almost-goodness is -1.
- If the almost-goodness of the rest of the string is -1, the almost-goodness is -1.
- Otherwise, if the first character is `1`, the almost-goodness is 1 plus the almost-goodness of the rest of the string.
- Otherwise, the first character must be `0`, and the almost-goodness is that of the rest of the string.

Goodness is derived from almost-goodness by treating -1 as 0.

---

Here is something better: a tail recursive `goodness`, with the passage of an explicit accumulator. This not allows the compiler to optimize it into a loop which means that it doesn't require an amount of stack space proportional to the length of the incoming string. As a bonus, the code is clearer, which is often the opposite with recursion rewritten to pass an accumulator:

```
static int almost_goodness(const char *str, int goodness_acc)
{
  if (goodness_acc < 0)
    return goodness_acc;

  switch (*str) {
  case 0:
    return goodness_acc;
  case '1':
    return almost_goodness(str + 1, 1 + goodness_acc);
  case '0':
    return almost_goodness(str + 1, goodness_acc);
  default:
    return -1;
  }
}

int goodness(const char *str)
{
  int ag = almost_goodness(str, 0);
  return ag < 0 ? 0 : ag;
}
```

Here the "(almost-)goodness accumulator" parameter `goodness_ac` represents "the goodness that we know so far about some earlier part of the string that we have already seen before".  If this value is -1, we don't have to bother processing the part of the string we are given.

---

Lastly, here is a purely iterative `goodness` function:

```
int goodness(const char *str)
{
  int g = 0;

  for (; *str; str++) {
    switch (*str) {
    case '0':
      break;
    case '1':
      g++;
      break;
    default:
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return g;
}
```

Very simple: loop through the string, incrementing a counter for every `1`, and skipping every `0`. If we see any other character, we bail immediately with zero regardless of the value of the counter.

Comment: you seem very informed on the matter of goodness. Is Almost-goodness different from goodness? And why would it be useful to know the goodness of a string in the future?

Comment: Everything I know about "goodness" comes from your question. I invented almost-goodness from goodness, because goodness is ambiguous: a 0 value of goodness has two meanings: "there are bad characters in the string" or "the string consists of nothing but zeros (or is empty)".  The ambiguity of goodness interferes with our ability to define goodness recursively.

Comment: How goodness differs from almost goodness is captured in the `goodness` function above: goodness takes almost-goodness and maps the -1 value to 0. If almost-goodness is non-negative, then it is the same as goodness. When almost-goodness is -1, that corresponds to goodness zero.

Comment: ohh i thought almost-goodness and goodness were actually something that developers would use on a day to day basis. A function of math or something along that line.

Comment: @TylerGee Nope; it's something that the teacher or textbook author made up for the homework assignment. It so happens that we can use goodness to illustrate recursion.

Comment: Note how none of the solutions count zeros! Counting zeros is pointless; zeros do not contribute anything to goodness, other than being tolerated as filler material between ones.